# Automatically refresh page on 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: javascript, http, nginx

When I’m doing maintenance on my site and restart the server, sometimes NGINX returns a 502 Bad Gateway error. The same thing sometimes happens under heavy load. This is confusing to my visitors who don’t realize the issue is probably temporary. Is there any way I can have visitors automatically refresh the page when the site is back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Javascript to check the HTTP status code for the current page, and refresh the page when the server is back up (i.e. returns the `200 OK` status code). To avoid hammering the server when many users encounter the `502` error page at once, I’d recommend using the [truncated binary exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) algorithm. This means the time between retries doubles each time up until a preset maximum, which lowers the overall load on your server.

The code below checks the current page HTTP status over AJAX until it returns `200 OK`, in which case it’ll refresh the page to get the live version. It will try retry if a `502` is encountered, starting at an 8 second interval, then 16, 32, …, 4096 seconds, then with unlimited subsequent retries at 4096 second intervals (about 68 minutes). If any code other than `502` or `200` is encountered, the retry process is silently aborted (though you could change this with more `case` statements if desired).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Currently unavailable</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Site currently unavailable (code 502)</h1>

  <p>This page will refresh when the site is back.</p>

  <noscript>Your browser doesn’t support javascript. Please try refreshing the page manually every few minutes.</noscript>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  /* Set starting and maximum retry times in seconds */
  var retry_current = 8, // first refresh at 8 seconds
      retry_max = 4096, // refresh time truncated at about 68 minutes
      check_response = function() {
      $.ajax(
          {
              url: window.location.href,
              type: "HEAD",
              complete: function (jqXHR) {
                  switch (jqXHR.status) {
                      case 200:
                          window.location.reload(true);
                          break;
                      case 502:
                          if(retry_current < retry_max) {
                              retry_current *= 2;
                          }
                          setTimeout(check_response, retry_current * 1000);
                  }
              }
          });
      };
    setTimeout(check_response, retry_current * 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you’re using nginx, you can add the following to your configuration file to use the page:

```
error_page 502 /502.html;
location = /502.html {
  alias /path/to/502.html;
}
```

Comment: I'm a newbie to Ajax but am facing a similar situation in which a page on my site times out randomly with a 500.0 error.  A refresh always restarts the page successfully, and I would like to do that with ajax/javascript only on that particular page.  
Is the code provided above for all 502 errors on a site (is the code to be placed only on the particular problematic webpage, or more of a sitewide solution)?  What confuses me is the descriptive language in the head and body "this page will refresh..." and "site currently unavailable" that suggests that this is a stand-alone page.

Comment: Would that language be used if this was a stand-alone page that was referenced by a configuration page, but not only a specific page?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! It worked for me. I've rewritten it to use fetch instead of jQuery, but I'm unable to make an edit due to the queue. Posting a separate answer. Please feel free to incorporate into the main answer when possible.

Answer (score 0):

A rewritten version of [lubstep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4177444/lubstep)'s answer, but using fetch instead of jQuery:

```
<script>
  let retry_current = 8; // first refresh at 8 seconds
  let retry_max = 4096; // refresh time truncated at about 68 minutes
  const check_response = async function () {
      console.log("Retrying in " + retry_current + " seconds");
      await fetch (window.location.href, {method: 'HEAD'})
           .then(response => {
               switch (response.status) {
                   case 200:
                       window.location.reload();
                       break;
                   case 502:
                       if (retry_current < retry_max) {
                           retry_current *= 2;
                       }
                    setTimeout(check_response, retry_current * 1000);
                }
            });
        };
    setTimeout(check_response, retry_current * 1000);
</script>
```

I'm unable, but please free to incorporate into the main answer if the queue and your rep allows.