# Automatic Reload Page On Error With Javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, refresh

I am working on an automatic refresh for when my page encounters a 500 error.  I found the jquery/javascript code online [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591222/automatically-refresh-page-on-502-bad-gateway-error), and as it was from an older posting, and is answered, it is no longer active.  I had a question about the way "check_response" is used below, as a variable, and then within the function (in 'setTimeout') set equal to the variable.  I'm a little rusty on my functions, and I was wondering if 'check_response' here is used both as a variable and as a command within Python?  In the OP question, Python was not one of the tags used, although I've noticed Python being related to 'check_response' after Googling it.
In short, can this script be used for non-Python appications?  Thanks.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   /* Set starting and maximum retry times in seconds */
   var retry_current = 8, // first refresh at 8 seconds
       retry_max = 4096, // refresh time truncated at about 68 minutes
       check_response = function() {
       $.ajax(
           {
               url: window.location.href,
               type: "HEAD",
               complete: function (jqXHR) {
              switch (jqXHR.status) {
                  case 200:
                      window.location.reload(true);
                      break;
                  case 502:
                      if(retry_current < retry_max) {
                          retry_current *= 2;
                      }
                      setTimeout(check_response, retry_current * 1000);
              }
          }
      });
  };
setTimeout(check_response, retry_current * 1000);
</script>
```

Below is the Javascript code for the page's main function: the loading of news items upon page refresh:

```
<script>
var reloadUrl = {{reloadUrl|json_encode|raw}};
window.setTimeout(function () {
window.location = reloadUrl;
}, 5000); //5 seconds
</script>
```

Comment: This is 100% JavaScript - you can use this code.

Comment: Thanks.  While the first occurrence of `check_response` appears to be a user defined variable, the second occurrence, I'm not sure about.  Is the 2nd `check_response` (that appears as an argument within `setTimeout`) the same value that was set in the first occurrence?  I'm not sure how it can get use the value.  Thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: `check_response` is a user-defined variable that references a function expression. That variable is used within the outer `setTimeout()` call to kick off a recursive function. It is used in the inner call to `setTimeout()` as a self-referential call. That literally says "If the connection times out (502), then retry the AJAX request by recalling this function. The recursion will continue until an HTTP 200 response is received or your retry counter is reached.

Comment: Thanks, that's a big help in the understanding of the logic!