# Intermittent 502 from nginx with rproxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

The config (I have tried experimenting with keepalives and connection limits, but it doesn't seem to matter):

```
resolver 1.1.1.1;
upstream placeholder {
    server something.com max_conns=1;
    keepalive 3;
}

server {
  server_name something.guru;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    sub_filter "https://something.com" "https://something.guru";
    sub_filter "https://something.net" "https://something.guru";
    sub_filter_once off;
    proxy_pass https://something.com;
    proxy_set_header Host something.com;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_ssl_verify off;
  }

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/something.guru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/something.guru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
}
```

The site on back end is a wordpress that's not written well and I don't have any control over it. For country-level firewall issues, I need to be able to forward traffic to it from the proxy.
The symptoms are: initial connection to site through proxy usually results in 502. Then upon refresh everything works fine. It will continue working fine as you are browsing, but if you take a break for a few mintues - you get 502 again.
This is the error I am getting in logs:

```
 *28558 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream
```

My question is - how can I improve user experience? I am OK to either tell nginx to try connecting to back end again without giving user a 502, or maybe there is some other configuration I can try in nginx to eliminate the issue altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to use some custom 502 error page (see the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591222/automatically-refresh-page-on-502-bad-gateway-error)). You'll need to add `proxy_intercept_errors on;` to your config for allowing use of custom error pages for proxied responses. You can also take a look at the HTTP `Refresh` header (an [article](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/how-to-refresh-a-page-in-an-interval-without-javascript/)) that can be added using `add_header Refresh ... always;` directive.

Comment: One more option can be the [`Retry-After`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) HTTP header. However an HTTP response code should be changed to 503 to use it: `error_page 502 =503 ...`

Comment: @IvanShatsky Both are great ideas, thank you very much!